# After clearing magento cache got error Opening and ending tag mismatch: /Varien/Simplexml/Config.php

Tags: php, magento, mage

After Clearing magento cache, got error. I enabled error reporting in magento and found error as below, and able to find the location of error

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 82: parser error :
>   Opening and ending tag mismatch: two_columns_healthcare_video line 78
>   and two_columns_healthcare  in
>   /home/mdmcomme/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
>
> 0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/home/mdmcomme/...', 510, Array)
>   1 /home/mdmcomme/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(510): simplexml_load_string('loadString('loadFile('/home/mdmcomme/...')
>
> 4 /home/mdmcomme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(318):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesConfiguration(Array,
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config))
>
> 5 /home/mdmcomme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(414):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
>
> 6 /home/mdmcomme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
>
> 7 /home/mdmcomme/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> 8 /home/mdmcomme/public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> 9 {main}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When cleaning magento cache Opening and ending tag mismatch: /Varien/Simplexml/Config.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696782/when-cleaning-magento-cache-opening-and-ending-tag-mismatch-varien-simplexml-c)

Comment: The error IS NOT in `lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php` but in a config file being read by it. Look for mismatched tags in `.xml` files. And this has already been answered here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696782/when-cleaning-magento-cache-opening-and-ending-tag-mismatch-varien-simplexml-c

Answer (score 0):

Please go to file lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php and update loadFile & loadString function as i mentioned. You will find the exact file name which having issue

```
public function loadFile($filePath)
    {
        if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
            //throw new Exception('Can not read xml file '.$filePath);
            return false;
        }

        $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
        $fileData = $this->processFileData($fileData);
        return $this->loadString($fileData, $this->_elementClass,$filePath);
    }


 public function loadString($string,$el,$filePath)
        {
            if (is_string($string)) {
                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);
                if (false === $xml) {
                  //$errors = libxml_get_errors();
                  echo "<br>";$filePath; die;
                }
                if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
                    $this->_xml = $xml;
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
            }
            return false;
        }
```